# Show multiple layers with only one trigger in Openlayers

Tags: events, openlayers

I am creating an Overlayers project with a lateral menu that allows me to turn on / off layers using a checkbox.

On the body of the HTML file I use the class= "visible0,1,2,3" to be a trigger for the fieldset.
HTML sample:

```
<fieldset id="layer0">
                <label class="checkbox" for="visible0">
                  <input id="visible0" class="visible" type="checkbox"/> <i class="fa-solid fa-flag" style="color:#009436"></i>Layer0 
                </label> 
                <label class="checkbox" for="visible1">
                   <input id="visible1" class="visible" type="checkbox"/> <i class="fa-solid fa-flag" style="color:#005994"></i>Layer1 
                </label>
```

For the main.js I define de map, the main base layer group used with a switcher function to change the map baselayer and vectorlayers that can be turned on and off with the html checkbox class.

```
// MAP
const map = new Map({
  view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat([3.4, 48.6]),
      zoom: 9.5
      //layers: layers,
    }),
  
  target: 'map'

// Layer Group for map base layer switcher

const baseLayerGroup = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'Base maps',
  layers: [
    openStreetMapStandard, openStreetHumanitarian, stamenTerrain, waterColor, osmFRHOT,
  ]
})

map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup);


    // Vector layers
   const layer0JSON = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: './data/vector_data/layer0.json',
        format: new GeoJSON(),     
        }),
        visible: false,
        title: 'layer0JSON',     
    })
map.addLayer(layer0JSON)

const layer1JSON = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
        url: './data/vector_data/layer1.json',
        format: new GeoJSON(),     
        }),
        visible: false,
        title: 'layer1JSON',     
})
map.addLayer(layer1JSON)

const layer2JSON = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: './data/vector_data/layer2.json',
        format: new GeoJSON(),     
        }),
        visible: false,
        title: 'layer2JSON',     
})
map.addLayer(layer2JSON)
```

Now that I have 3 layers defined, I create a group with layers 1 and 2 and use a function to turn on the elements:

```
const group1 = new LayerGroup({
  title: 'group1',
  layers: [
    layer1JSON, layer2JSON,
  ]
})

map.addLayer(group1);

// Menu function on off

var bindLayerButtonToggle = (btnId, layer) => {
  document.getElementById(btnId).onclick = function () {
    layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible());
  };
}

// on off menu 
bindLayerButtonToggle("visible0", layer0JSON);
bindLayerButtonToggle("visible1", group1);
```

Everything works if the layer on the bindlayerButtonToggle is a simple layer but not if its a group. I wonder if  there is a conflict with  the baselayergroup. I tried to define all Layergroups in the map, tried to load multiple json files from a single VectorLayer const but no luck.

Any idea to solve this situation.

Comment: A layer can only be added to the map once, so if it is in a group it cannot also be added directly.

Comment: Thank you, that gives me an idea on how to tackle the problem.